# SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected , (10:10)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm practicing JavaScript code with this. https://rationalappdev.com/api-backend-with-nodejs-express-and-mongodb-for-react-native-apps/

I'm trying to change DB part with my own code, but when I run this at the terminal, 
[image]

this error occurs.

and this is **baby.js**'s code.

```
    import mongoose,{ Schema } from 'mongoose';

    var babySchema = new Schema({
      info:
        { size:
          { width: number, height: number },
           faceCount: number
        },
      faces:
        [ roi :
          { x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number },
          landmark:
            { leftEye: { x: number, y: number },
            rightEye: { x: number, y: number },
            nose: { x: number, y: number },
            leftMouth: { x: number, y: number },
            rightMouth: { x: number, y: number }},
          gender: { value: String, confidence: number },
          age: { value: String, confidence: number },
          emotion: { value: String, confidence: number },
          pose: { value: String, confidence: number }
        ]
      });

      export default mongoose.mode('baby', babySchema);
```

Comment: Try changing `faces: [ .. ]` to `faces {... }`

Comment: `[]` is an array. there are no associative arrays in js, you probably want an object: `{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `:` only in objects to assign a value and not in an array. So you need to wrap `roi: ...` in `{roi: }`:

```
var babySchema = new Schema({
  info:
    { size:
      { width: number, height: number },
       faceCount: number
    },
  faces:
    [ {roi :
      { x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number },
      landmark:
        { leftEye: { x: number, y: number },
        rightEye: { x: number, y: number },
        nose: { x: number, y: number },
        leftMouth: { x: number, y: number },
        rightMouth: { x: number, y: number }},
      gender: { value: String, confidence: number },
      age: { value: String, confidence: number },
      emotion: { value: String, confidence: number },
      pose: { value: String, confidence: number }
    }]
  });
```

If the attribute `faces` should not be an array, just remove the `[]` around the `roi` object.

Comment: That's also possible, but I don't know, if he wants an array of faces or not